# Writing a Spark data frame to SQL Server (atomic transaction)?

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark

I have a requirement to write a large Spark data frame to SQL Server.
This is a batch job that runs using Spark 1.6.1 and Python 2.7 once every day.

Options:

1. **append:** If the job fails (due to data type truncation, connection issue, etc.), it ends up writing partial data to SQL Server (not atomic).
2. **overwrite:** The table is being deleted and created instead of truncation (all data types end up as text in the SQL Server destination table)
3. **pandas:** If I convert the Spark data frame to a pandas data frame, I achieve atomicity, but it's not scalable

Can someone please suggest the best approach (without using a staging table)?

Comment: Where does the data _come from_? Could you instead stream each "row" into something like Kafka for durability, then Kafka can be read into JDBC records to be inserted? Plus, then you no longer are waiting 24 hours for your data... Just a thought. If not, you should really consider upgrading to Spark 2 and Python 3 for future maintainability of these scripts

Comment: We cannot use kafka as its not a streaming job. its a simple batchjob.
we hit the rest urls (json data) and make a spark dataframe out of it by ingesting schema. then persisting the data to sql server.

Comment: Okay. You could still hit rest APIs, parse JSON, and generate Kafka records in a batch job. Only consumers of Kafka are streaming real-time. But anyway, I'm not sure why you'd want to convert a Spark dataframe to Pandas. That'll likely overwhelm the Spark driver and doesn't have any performance improvements over the other options... And even if you overwrite, the job can still fail with partial data in between two requests, so you if you absolutely want all possible received data to be in the database at all times, despite connection/network issues, I'd say use appends